# ip address and mask in CIDR with python

Tags: python, ip

I would like to convert ipaddress/mask in ipaddress/CIDR:
For that two variables:

```
i = '192.168.0.0'
m = '255.255.255.0'
```

The result I'm trying to obtain is:

```
p to be: '192.168.0.0/24'
```

by using ipaddress module it would be super simple to just define like:

```
p = ipaddress.ip_network(i/m)
```

unfortunately, I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str' which is not surprising.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It works with:

```
p = ipaddress.ip_network(i+"/"+m)
```

Cheers